# use ng-repeat with fixed number of times

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use ng-repeat with a fixed number of iterations. Below I am trying to plunker, but I am getting an error. So I'm wondering where I should write `getTimes()` in my Code.

**My code ::**
 plnkr.co/edit/POjQta4kFlCrJfZAFkQc?p=preview

**what i am trying to use ::**
http://plnkr.co/edit/j5kNLY4Xr43CzcjM1gkj?p=preview

**Directive ::**

```
   <my-dir 
            bgcolor="#EFF"
            my-title="Iram" 
            my-height="200"
            my-width="450"
            my-color="cyan"
            my-bgcolor="pink"
            my-collapseoption=true
            my-widgetno="1"
            save="saveChanges('custom directive')">template
          </my-dir>
```

**ng-Directive ::**

```
app.directive("myDir", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      items:"=",
      myTitle: "@",   // by value
      myHeight: "@",   // by value
      myWidth: "@",   // by value
      myColor: "@",   // by value
      myBgcolor: "@",   // by value
      myWidgetno: "@", // by reference
      myCollapseoption: "@", // by reference            
      save: "&"    // event
    },

    templateUrl:"widget.html", 
      //"<div><h2>  And This is Title{{myTitle}} </div>",
    replace: true,
    transclude: false,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        // show initial values: by-val members will be undefined
       console.log("items is " +scope.items);


        // change element just to show we can
        element.css("background", attrs.myBgcolor);
        element.css("color", attrs.myColor);
        element.css("width", attrs.myWidth+'px');
       // element.css("height", attrs.myHeight+'px');

    }
  }
});
```

**Template ::**

```
   <div>

<div class="panel panel-primary" ng-repeat="t in getTimes(4) | limitTo:2"> 
            <div class="panel-heading"> 
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span>{{myTitle}}{{items}}
                <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-show="myCollapseoption" ng-click="checked=!checked">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down "></span>
                    </button>                        
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body collapsible" ng-init="checked=true" ng-show="checked"  ng-style="{'background-color':'pink'}" style="clear:both;">
            This is the middle Content <br/><br/><br/>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What error!!! its working fine here http://plnkr.co/edit/zG8Mr4REnugAOibAqNwC?p=preview

Comment: @JayShukla http://plnkr.co/edit/POjQta4kFlCrJfZAFkQc?p=preview  see not woring here..

Comment: @JayShukla I am using it indside directives

Comment: I'm not getting any error in console. It looks like all working fine. what error you are getting?

Comment: @JayShukla did u tried my plunker ?? directive are not displayed when getTime() used , without it or placed [1,2,3] it will work .http://plnkr.co/edit/POjQta4kFlCrJfZAFkQc?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write `controller` for that directive.
Like this:

```
controller: function($scope) {
     $scope.getTimes=function(n){
        return new Array(n);
     };  
}
```

See working [<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vzu40owODkLNHAoHjvGC?p=preview)

**Why `track by $index` with ng-repeat**

As you are returning array having duplicate values, it will throws an error of duplicate values not allowed. You can solve this issue using `track by` as I've done or you can modify `getTimes` function which creates an array with unique values.

**UPDATE**

When you pass variable, its not working because the value is string.

```
var a = new Array("3")
```

The above statement will create an array of length 1 i.e ["1"]. This is what problem is.

You need to update statement as below:

```
controller: function($scope) {
     $scope.getTimes=function(n){
         return new Array(parseInt(n));
     };  
}
```

Updated code - [See here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xOOKGif1pZ9yFseTRGVI?p=preview)

Comment: thanks ... i wrote same thing but getting same "duplicate error". thanks to introduce me trackby Option . have a nice day !

Comment: i have updated ur plunker to pass  variable in getTimes but it is not displaying properly .. http://plnkr.co/edit/Vzu40owODkLNHAoHjvGC?p=preview

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/xWfFHyDO2PFpEReL9ux1?p=preview   value of myWidgetno is passed to directive but inside getTimes it is not working

Comment: Also i checkd inside getTimes(), value of n is passed correctly there

Comment: :) Thanks parsing huuuhhh